# How do I change HOSTNAME on an Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, hostname

I'm attempting to change the hostname on my shared server with Slicehost so I can setup Postfix as a null client.

I edited /etc/hosts
and after reboot, the hostname is still incorrect.
What am I doing wrong?

```
username@mail Fri Jul 01 13:01:32 ~   
$ sudo cat /etc/hostname  
mail.domain1.com  

username@mail Fri Jul 01 13:01:45 ~   
$ cat /etc/hosts  
127.0.0.1     localhost localhost.localdomain  
208.78.100.198  mail.domain1.com   

username@mail Fri Jul 01 13:02:13 ~   
$ hostname -f  
pop.where.secureserver.net
```

I also intend to add another domain to this server, how do I configure this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the second line in hosts to `208.78.100.198  mail.domain1.com mail`. Also, rebooting is not necessary: the FQDN isn't stored anywhere, it's looked up on-the-fly.

I believe that the FQDN is found by doing a DNS query on the server's IP address, then taking the first response, which is why this works. It should be possible to set the FQDN without modifying hosts by using only DNS (or NIS, or LDAP, or wherever else `nsswitch.conf` looks for hosts) but if it's in the hosts file there's no need for network traffic that might time out or otherwise cause problems in an emergency.

**More information**
Here's everything that happens (this is Linux-only, other OSes may and will do things somewhat differently):

`hostname` uses the `gethostname(2)` function specified in `unistd.h` to obtain the hostname. This function is implemented as a call to `uname(2)`, where the `nodename` field of the structure is extracted and returned. This will have been set earlier in the boot process with the corresponding `sethostname(2)` call, since the kernel has no other way of knowing the host's name. In your case, it will be `mail`. (By the way, this is what you should have in `/etc/hostname`).

This is then resolved using the standard system resolver, which will be either `getaddrinfo(3)` or `gethostbyname(3)` depending upon the vintage of your system utils. The field `h_name`, defined as "official name of host", gets returned. I believe this corresponds to the first name listed in a hosts file.

As for your multiple domains question, `hostname` is not able to deal properly with multiple names. Every interface (even virtual ones) can have its own IP and sometimes even multiple physical interfaces can share an IP.

You should ensure that each IP attached to your host resolves via reverse-IP lookups to the appropriate name and configure your mail server properly.